# Custom migrations for PostgreSQL Materialized View with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm trying to auto-generate migrations for materialized views in SQLAlchemy, and the only thing that's not working is detecting changes between revisions. More specifically, it *always* generates a change, even when the model hasn't changed.

I think the problem is, and I could just be using the wrong approach here, is the difference between the SQL generated by `schema.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True})` and the SQL returned by `inspector.get_view_definition(name)`.

Backing up, here's what the **model definition** looks like, just a simple adjacency list tree. The goal of using the materialized view is the automatically generate a node's depth and path in such a way that it can be queried against:

```
from app.extensions import db  # Flask-SQLAlchemy

@db.slugify('name')
class Node(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, index=True)
    slug = db.Column(db.String, index=True)

    parent_id = db.foreign_key('Node', nullable=True)
    parent = db.relationship('Node', back_populates='children', remote_side=id)
    children = db.relationship('Node', back_populates='parent')

    mv = db.relationship('NodeMV', uselist=False, foreign_keys='NodeMV.id',
                         primaryjoin='Node.id == NodeMV.id')
    depth = db.association_proxy('mv', 'depth')
    path = db.association_proxy('mv', 'path')

_cte = (db.select([Node.id.label('id'),
                   literal(0).label('depth'),
                   literal('/').label('path')])
        .where(Node.parent_id is None)
        .cte(name='nodes_cte', recursive=True))
_union = _cte.union_all(
    db.select([
        Node.id.label('id'),
        label('depth', _cte.c.depth + 1),
        label('path', case([(_cte.c.depth == 0, _cte.c.path + Node.slug)],
                           else_=_cte.c.path + '/' + Node.slug))])
    .select_from(db.join(_cte, Node, _cte.c.id == Node.parent_id))
)

class NodeMV(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'node_mv'
    __table__ = create_materialized_view('node_mv', db.select([_union]))

db.Index('ix_node_mv_id', NodeMV.id, unique=True)
```

Where the **`create_materialized_view` factory method** looks like this:

```
def create_materialized_view(name, selectable, metadata=db.metadata):
    # must use a temporary metadata here so that SQLAlchemy doesn't detect the
    # table as "standalone". (it will still use the correct metadata once
    # attached to the __table__ attribute of the declarative base model)
    table = db.Table(name, db.MetaData())
    for col in selectable.c:
        table.append_column(
            db.Column(col.name, col.type, primary_key=col.primary_key))

    if not any([col.primary_key for col in selectable.c]):
        table.append_constraint(
            db.PrimaryKeyConstraint(*[col.name for col in selectable.c]))

    # to support using db.drop_all()
    db.event.listen(metadata, 'before_drop',
                    db.DDL(f'DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS {name}'))

    # to support auto-generated migrations
    metadata.info.setdefault('materialized_views', set()).add(
        (name, selectable))
    metadata.info.setdefault('materialized_tables', {})[name] = table

    return table
```

And the **migrations comparator** that detects changes:

```
class ReplaceableSql:
    def __init__(self, name, create_sql, drop_sql, indexes, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.create_sql = create_sql
        self.drop_sql = drop_sql
        self.indexes = indexes
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ReplaceableSql):
            return False
        return self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()

    def __hash__(self):
        key = (self.name, re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', self.create_sql), self.indexes)
        return hash(key)

def create_replaceable_sql(name, schema, metadata):
    query = (schema if isinstance(schema, str)
                    else schema.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
    indexes = [(index.name, [c.name for c in index.columns], index.unique)
               for index in metadata.info['materialized_tables'][name].indexes]
    return ReplaceableSql(name,
                          f'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW {name} AS {query}',
                          f'DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS {name}',
                          indexes)

@comparators.dispatch_for('schema')
def compare_views(autogen_context, upgrade_ops, schemas):
    inspector = autogen_context.inspector
    metadata = autogen_context.metadata
    prev_revision = autogen_context.migration_context.get_current_revision()

    # existing views
    views = set()
    view_names = set()
    for schema in schemas:
        for name in inspector.get_view_names(include='materialized', schema=schema):
            views.add(create_replaceable_sql(
                name, inspector.get_view_definition(name, schema=schema), metadata))
            view_names.add(name)

    # current metadata views
    metadata_views = set()
    metadata_view_names = set()
    for name, selectable in metadata.info.setdefault('materialized_views', set()):
        metadata_views.add(create_replaceable_sql(name, selectable, metadata))
        metadata_view_names.add(name)

    creates = metadata_views.difference(views)
    drops = views.difference(metadata_views)
    upgrades = view_names.intersection(metadata_view_names)

    for replaceable_sql in creates:
        name = replaceable_sql.name
        if name in upgrades:
            replaceable_sql.kwargs['prev'] = f'{prev_revision}.{name}'
        upgrade_ops.ops.append(CreateOp(replaceable_sql))

    for replaceable_sql in drops:
        if replaceable_sql.name in upgrades:
            continue
        upgrade_ops.ops.append(DropOp(replaceable_sql))
```

The differences in inspected vs generated SQL are minor (ignoring whitespace), but they're enough to throw off a string comparison:

**inspector.get_view_definition(table_name)**:

```
WITH RECURSIVE nodes_cte(id, depth, path) AS (
    SELECT
      node.id,
      0 AS depth,
      '/'::text AS path
    FROM node
    WHERE false
  UNION ALL
    SELECT
      node.id,
      (nodes_cte_1.depth + 1) AS depth,
      CASE
        WHEN (nodes_cte_1.depth = 0) THEN (nodes_cte_1.path || (node.slug)::text)
        ELSE ((nodes_cte_1.path || '/'::text) || (node.slug)::text)
      END AS path
    FROM (nodes_cte nodes_cte_1
    JOIN node ON ((nodes_cte_1.id = node.parent_id)))
)
SELECT nodes_cte.id, nodes_cte.depth, nodes_cte.path FROM nodes_cte;
```

**schema.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True})**:

```
WITH RECURSIVE nodes_cte(id, depth, path) AS (
    SELECT
      node.id AS id,
      0 AS depth,
      '/' AS path
    FROM node
    WHERE false
  UNION ALL
    SELECT
      node.id AS id,
      nodes_cte.depth + 1 AS depth,
      CASE
        WHEN (nodes_cte.depth = 0) THEN nodes_cte.path || node.slug
        ELSE nodes_cte.path || '/' || node.slug
      END AS path
    FROM nodes_cte
    JOIN node ON nodes_cte.id = node.parent_id
)
SELECT nodes_cte.id, nodes_cte.depth, nodes_cte.path FROM nodes_cte
```

So I suppose the question is, what's the correct approach I should be taking here? (It's also possible that using a materialized view is the wrong way to solve my problem - I did try using the `@hybrid_property`/`@prop_name.expression` stuff but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with the recursive nature of the data.)

Thanks in advance!